# Why does MongoDB update always result in error response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Why is a successful update response always passed as an error. is something wrong with my code or is it the Mongo DB response.

However I don't see any errors when I check them on MongoDB.

MongoDB Enterprise > db.getLastError();
null

Response:

```
{
  "lastErrorObject": {
    "n": 1,
    "updatedExisting": true
  },
  "value": {
    "_id": "1111111111",
    "xyz": "hgfjdfjk"
  }
}
```

Code Block

```
{
            try {
                const db = client.db(dbName);
                db.collection(cName).updateOne({ _id: id }, { $pull: query }).then((err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        callBack(err);
                    } else {
                        callBack(null, result);
                    }
                });
                client.close();
            }
            catch (err) {
                callBack({
                    error: 'Unable to process the request',
                    errorMessage: err
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you're working with Promises, `then` doesn't pass an error.

Comment: you can try ``` db.collection(cName).updateOne({ _id: id }, { $pull: query }).then(( result) => {
                                          callBack(null, result);
                    
                }).catch(err)=>{
  callBack(err);
}); 
```

Answer (score 1):

`getLastError()` returns the server response to the current operation within that connection, and is not related to an actual error in MongoDB. It is part of MongoDB's [wire protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/index.html).

See [getLastError](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getLastError/) for more details.